# Running Mariadb with Docker but getting empty database

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

So I have access inside my virtual machine to run mysql with the following commands:
mysql -h (IP for mariadb) -u (user) -p (password) databasename
Now, when I try creating the following commands to run mariadb inside of a docker container: [ref] ([how to remote access to mariadb on docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59591620/how-to-remote-access-to-mariadb-on-docker)). Then, when I do show tables it says **Empty set (0.000 sec)**. I don't know why I am not able to see the data through docker. I tried using docker ip for the container as well and same thing as well. Does anyone know a way around this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I just had to do something like this - Sometimes, you need to specify the port for the Server or to force TCP mode:

```
mysql -h 173.18.0.2 -P 3308 --protocol=TCP -u root -p
```